# Responsive 3d cube - bottom moving on y axis with viewport resize

Tags: html, css, 3d, css-transforms

I'm trying to make a **responsive rectangular prism** with depth that will **resize with the window**.  But, no matter what I do, I can't get the bottom side to work correctly.  It only lines up on the Z axis when the viewport has a square aspect ratio.
I had the same issue with the top side moving when I had it set to translateY(-50vh), but it starting behaving how I wanted when I changed it to -50vw (for some reason I can't figure out).

How can I make the bottom responsive like the top?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jwBQGR

```css
.scene {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  perspective: 3000px;
}

.rectangle {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: translateZ(-50vw);
}

.side {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: visible;
}

.back {
  transform: translateZ(-50vw);
  background-color: saddlebrown;
}

.top {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 100vw;
  transform: translateY(-50vw) rotateX(-90deg);
}

.bottom {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100vw;
  transform: translateY(50vh) rotateX(90deg);
}

.front {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.left {
  background-color: sandybrown;
  transform: translateX(-50vw) rotateY(-90deg);
}

.right {
  background-color: brown;
  transform: translateX(50vw) rotateY(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="scene">
  <div class="rectangle" id="cubeID">
    <div class="side back">
      <h1>Back</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="side top">
      <h1>Top </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="side bottom">
      <h1>Bottom</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="side front">
      <h1>Front</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="side left">
      <h1>Left</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="side right">
      <h1>Right</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: .scene {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0 auto 0;
    perspective: 3000px;
    background: green;
}

Try this, a quick hack.

Answer (score 0):

The point is to use the `transform-origin` property (see [transform-origin on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin?v=control)). This way, you can control the rotation axis for each side rather than repositioning them with translation after they have been rotated as you did.

Here is an example :

```css
body,html{margin:0;}
.scene {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  perspective: 3000px;
}

.rectangle {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.side {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: visible;
}

.back {
  transform: translateZ(-100vw);
  background-color: saddlebrown;
}
.top {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height:100vw;
  transform-origin:50% 0;
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
}
.bottom {
  background-color: green;
  height:100vw;
  bottom:0;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
}
.front {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.left {
  background-color: sandybrown;
  transform-origin:0 50%;
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
}
.right {
  background-color: brown;
  transform-origin:100% 50%;
  transform: rotateY(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="scene">
  <div class="rectangle" id="cubeID">
    <div class="side back"><h1>Back</h1></div>
    <div class="side top"><h1>Top </h1></div>
    <div class="side bottom"><h1>Bottom</h1></div>
    <div class="side front"><h1>Front</h1></div>
    <div class="side left"><h1>Left</h1></div>
    <div class="side right"><h1>Right</h1></div>
  </div>
</div>
```